# A simple question about the center of a finite  group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ a characteristic subgroup of $N$: 
$$K \text{ char } N \triangleleft G.$$
If $Z(G/N)=1$ and $Z(G)=1$, does it follow that $Z(G/K)=1$?

Comment: As you state the question, no. What it $G$ is any finite group with $Z(G) = 1$ and we take $N = G, K =[G,G]$? Then $Z(G) = Z(G/N) = 1$ and $G/K$ is Abelian (here, $[G,G]$ means the derived group).

Comment: Thanks a lot,however,if we add an other condition $1<$K<$H<G$.May you get another counter-example.

Comment: For a finite vector space $V$ over the finite field $\mathbb F$ take the semi-direct product $V \rtimes \mathop{GL}_{\mathbb F}(V)$.

Comment: jp, what are K, N and G in your example?

Comment: This is not a research level question, so is not suitable for MO. With the question as it is worded now, a counterexample is $S_3 \times A_5$, with $N=S_3$, $|K|=3$.

Comment: @Nick: As I totally agree with Derek that this question is not research level at all, I left it to the reader to figure out what is what. Hint: $\mathrm{GL}_{\mathbb F}(V)$ has non-trivial center (and too small fields and vector spaces don't work).

Answer (score 2):

As it is not entirely clear where the containments are meant to be, I will assume you are asking about the case $N\triangleleft K\triangleleft G$; in this case $Z(G) = Z(G/N) = 1$ is not sufficient in general to guarantee $Z(G/K)$ is also trivial. As an example, take $N$ to be the Klein-4 subgroup of $S_4$ and $K = A_4$. Then $G/N\cong S_3$ so $Z(G) = Z(G/N)$ is trivial, but $G/K$ is abelian (isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) and so $Z(G/K)$ is not trivial.

Comment: I am sorry.It is not the case.It is $K$char$N\triangleleft G$. Thank you all the same. 